# Cocoa IB Elements to Create a Report

Tags: xcode, cocoa, interface-builder, nsoutlineview

I'm developing an app to display Activities and the Laps within the Activities. I'm fairly new to Cocoa, but have created a basic interface to display the contents of the Activities array and then respond to a button to display the Laps and some summary data for all the selected Activities. Here are the class structures:

Activity Class:

- activityDate
- sport
- laps[]

Lap Class:

- startTime
- totalTime
- distance
- maximumSpeed
- averageSpeed
- maximumPace
- averagePace
- calories
- averageHeartbeat
- maximumHeartbeat
- intensity

What I really want to do is display a report view that shows each selected Activity with its Lap details and summary and a grand summary at the bottom, which I can print.

```
Running  Oct-22-2011 10:10:14 AM
              Lap 1  10:10:14 AM  3.80 mi  42:48   11:16/mi  ...
                          Summary 3.80 mi  42:48   11:16/mi  ...

Running  Oct-24-2011 04:07:06 PM
         Lap 1  04:07:06 PM  3.10 mi  31:19   10:06/mi  ...
         Lap 2  04:38:31 PM  3.10 mi  31:16   10:05/mi  ...
                    Summary  6.20 mi  1:02:36 10:05/mi ....

              Grand Summary  10.0 mi  1:45:25 10:29/mi  ...
```

The summaries are totals and averages depending on the value. I want column headings and possible row highlighting for the summaries.

I've looked at possibly using an NSOutlineView, as I want everything to be nicely aligned in columns, but don't know how to use two different classes for the display. I tried once to do this using HTML to create a NSTextView, with okay results. However, I really don't want to generate HTML to solve this.

Any ideas and possible examples?

Answer (score 0):

After research, I could not find a way to implement the interface I wanted in IB. I went back to using a WebView and HTML to generate the report results. Using tables and CSS, I was able to create a rather pleasant looking set of reports that can print easily.

Here is the HTML generated, as I cannot post an image (I'm too new to stackoverflow).

```
    <table class='first'>
        <tr class='activity'><td>Running</td><td colspan='10' align='left'>Oct 2, 2011 11:29 AM</td></tr>
        <tr class='lap'><th></th><th>Start Time</th><th>Distance</th><th>Elapsed Time</th><th>Avg Pace</th><th>Max Pace</th><th>Avg Speed</th><th>Max Speed</th><th>Calories</th><th>Avg Heartrate</th><th>Max Heartrate</th></tr>
        <tr class='lapdetails'><td></td><td class='lap'>11:29:53 AM</td><td class='lap'>3.68 mi</td><td class='lap'>38:21.62</td><td class='lap'>10:25/mi</td><td class='lap'>5:43/mi</td><td class='lap'>5.8 mph</td><td class='lap'>10.5 mph</td><td class='lap'>449</td><td class='lap'>0</td><td class='lap'>0</td></tr>
        <tr class='activitysummary'><td>Totals:</td><td class='lap'></td><td class='lap'>3.68 mi</td><td class='lap'>38:21.62</td><td class='lap'>10:25/mi</td><td class='lap'>5:43/mi</td><td class='lap'>5.8 mph</td><td class='lap'>10.5 mph</td><td class='lap'>449</td><td class='lap'>0</td><td class='lap'>0</td></tr>
    </table>
    <table>
        <tr class='activity'><td>Running</td><td colspan='10' align='left'>Oct 7, 2011 12:22 PM</td></tr>
        <tr class='lap'><th></th><th>Start Time</th><th>Distance</th><th>Elapsed Time</th><th>Avg Pace</th><th>Max Pace</th><th>Avg Speed</th><th>Max Speed</th><th>Calories</th><th>Avg Heartrate</th><th>Max Heartrate</th></tr>
        <tr class='lapdetails'><td></td><td class='lap'>12:22:59 PM</td><td class='lap'>3.18 mi</td><td class='lap'>31:17.35</td><td class='lap'>9:49/mi</td><td class='lap'>6:44/mi</td><td class='lap'>6.1 mph</td><td class='lap'>8.9 mph</td><td class='lap'>402</td><td class='lap'>148</td><td class='lap'>171</td></tr>
        <tr class='activitysummary'><td>Totals:</td><td class='lap'></td><td class='lap'>3.18 mi</td><td class='lap'>31:17.35</td><td class='lap'>9:49/mi</td><td class='lap'>6:44/mi</td><td class='lap'>6.1 mph</td><td class='lap'>8.9 mph</td><td class='lap'>402</td><td class='lap'>148</td><td class='lap'>171</td></tr>
    </table>
    <table>
        <tr class='activity'><td colspan='11'>Summary</td></tr>
        <tr class='lap'><th></th><th>Activities</th><th>Distance</th><th>Elapsed Time</th><th>Avg Pace</th><th>Max Pace</th><th>Avg Speed</th><th>Max Speed</th><th>Calories</th><th>Avg Heartrate</th><th>Max Heartrate</th></tr>
        <tr class='activitysummary'><td class='lap'></td><td class='lap'>2</td><td class='lap'>6.86 mi</td><td class='lap'>1:09:38.97</td><td class='lap'>10:07/mi</td><td class='lap'>5:43/mi</td><td class='lap'>5.9 mph</td><td class='lap'>10.5 mph</td><td class='lap'>851</td><td class='lap'>148</td><td class='lap'>171</td></tr>
        <tr class='activitysummary'><td class='lap'></td><td class='lap'>per Activity</td><td class='lap'>3.43 mi</td><td class='lap'>34:49.49</td><td class='lap'>10:07/mi</td><td class='lap'>&nbsp;</td><td class='lap'>5.9 mph</td><td class='lap'>&nbsp;</td><td class='lap'>425</td><td class='lap'>&nbsp;</td><td class='lap'>&nbsp;</td></tr>
    </table>
```